# SQL Server 2008 Trigger Sql Job from bat file

Tags: sql-server-2008, batch-file, sql-agent-job

How can i trigger an SQL job from a bat file?

I will need to input my credentials: user and password, the bat file will be sitting on the server and i want folks to execute bat by double click over windows explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

Cheers guys.
sqlcmd -Sxxxx -Uxxxx -Pxxxx -dxxxx -Q"exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job xxxxxx"

Answer (score 1):

SQLCMD is what you need.
SQLCMD /?

Comment: need more info than that dude.

Comment: Do something like user2793797 posted in a bat file.  Except use SQLCMD instead of osql because osql is deprecated.  Do SQLCMD /? to get help.  If you need the exact command, then post all the specifics (Server name, etc). Show what you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

CD C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn

osql -S “[SQL SERVER NAME]” -E -Q”exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job ‘[SQL JOB NAME]‘”

Comment: Do i put this in a bat file?